# Function that must filter out numbers above 100 and below -100 in a row and find the minimum value

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA function Loss that reads the 11th row of another worksheet and finds the minimum value on the row.

However, the minimum's absolute value must be less than 100. (The row displays both percentages and regular values and I only need the minimum percentage.)

Furthermore, once I have the value of the minimal value in the 11th row, I want to assign the value of the cell right above to a variable, thanks to the function Worst.

Here is what I have so far, thanks to the help of answers in a previous question I asked:

```
Function Loss(worksheet1 As Worksheet) As Double

    Dim min As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myRight As Long, Colcount As Long

    min = 100

    With worksheet1
        myRight = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For Colcount = 4 To myRight
            If (.Cells(11, Colcount).Value < min) And (Abs(.Cells(11, Colcount).Value) <= 100) Then
                min = .Cells(11, Colcount).Value
            End If
        Next Colcount
    End With

    Loss = min

End Function
```

```
Function Worst(worksheet1 As Worksheet) As String

    Dim min As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myRight As Long, Colcount As Long

    min = 100

    With worksheet1
        myRight = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For Colcount = 4 To myRight
             If (.Cells(11, Colcount).Value < min) And (Abs(.Cells(11, Colcount).Value) <= 100) Then
                 min = .Cells(11, Colcount).Value
                  Worst = .Cells(10, Colcount).Value
             End If
        Next Colcount
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: See my answer to your previous question about incorporating `IsNumeric` to avoid a `Type Mismatch`.

Comment: What happens when your minimum value isn't unique?   That is, the smallest value in row 11 is greater than -100 is -94, but you have more than one -94?

Comment: it is most certainly going to be unique since the values are doubles with many decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the difficult task into artifacts.

```
Worst _ 
Сell_Minimum( _
Range_of_Values_without_Percent (_
Range_get))
```

' Like most VBA programmers, you want to do a lot of actions in one procedure - this leads to complexity.
' Let 's simplify - let's write simple monosyllabic methods whose chain will inevitably solve the problem.

```
Function Range_get(Optional ByVal sMsg As String) _
        As Range
' Your simple CODE
'
End Function

Function Range_of_Values_without_Percent(ByVal r As Range) _
        As Range
' Your simple CODE
'
End Function

Function Cell_Minimum(ByVal r As Range) _
        As Range
' Your simple CODE
'
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Should I filter out the values that aren't percentages first then find the minimum?

Comment: Yes!Please see my next answer